# When to use hexadecimal Identifiers in Java

Tags: java, performance, radix, hex

Is it recommended to use Hexadecimal numbers (base 16) for ID numbers ?

For Example:  Lets say i have a few objects or threads and i wanted to give them an ID and i used 0xF00D  and 0xF00B

My question then is:  what is the advantage of this over just using base 10 IDs like 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Use hex when it is more convenient to represent values as hex.  I'm not sure what else there is to say on that...

Comment: Hex integers perform much better and take less space than decimal integers ... NOT!  If it's a numeric constant ... just use whatever notation is more readable in your code.  It's as simple as that :)

Comment: thanks for the hint on performance gain and space.   so if i had a constant defined like public static int final aNumber=0xF00D;    would it be more efficient as opposed to public static int final aNumber=3;

Comment: `public static int final aNumber=0xF00D;` *IS COMPLETELY EQUIVALENT* to `public static int final aNumber=3;`.  *THERE IS NO DIFFERENCE*!